# Safari showing images transparent

Tags: wordpress, safari

I have one interesting issue on [this](http://rentluxcar.ru/) project, which is actively using **Visual Composer WP Plugin**.

When one of my clients tries to view the site on

- **MacBook Air OS X El Capitan**
- **Safari v. 9.0.1 (11601.2.7.2)**

the browser does not show any images on the main page. They are all loaded to the DOM and can be saved and then opened like a separate file, but on the web page it is just an empty space (smth like css `{opacity: 0}` rule).

I've been looking for some articles on this issue, but most of them refer to official forums and browser settings fixes. But it is not the case, as this client has a complete user experience on other web pages. And I must say it'is working fine on all the other major desktop and mobile browsers.

### Update

Tested with

- **Safari 8.0.4 (10600.4.10.7)**
- **MacBook Pro OS X Yosemite**

works like a charm

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is "seeking code help". I'm mostly looking for opinions share with other users who might experience Safari image rendering issues. As I've mentioned the page is perfectly displayed in all other major desktop and mobile browsers. I would also provide some code snippets with pleasure, but it would be nothing but regular HTML like DIV with an IMG inside. The issue is quite unique.

Comment: If we can't reproduce it then this question is unlikely to be a good fit for Stack Overflow...as you say, the issue is unique.

Comment: If you can't see the problem yourself, it's very difficult to debug; we'd all be groping in the dark? Does the client have an ad blocker? Do you have other clients with the same platform and do they experience it too?

Comment: see: http://metzgeralbee.com/our-thoughts/user-experience-gone-wild-safari-9/